# If the integral over an area is zero is the integral of the gradient also zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Say I know that $\int\int v_z dx dy = 0$ over some area with $dA = dx dy$. $v_z$ is a function of $x$ that "points" in $z$. Is this enough to say that $\int\int \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial x} dx dy = 0$ ?

Thanks

Comment: If $v_z$ is a function of $x$, then why the need for the partial derivatives?  If $v_z$ is a function of $x$ then $\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial x} = \frac{dv_z}{dx}$, right?

Comment: Right. Right. Right.

Comment: I would think this doesn't hold, in general, because because I can think of a single variable case like $\int_{-a}^a \sin(x) dx = 0$ but $\int_{-a}^a \cos(x)dx \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Let $v_z = (0,0,x)$ and the region of integration be the unit circle.  Clearly, by symmetry, $\int \int v_z \mathrm{d}A = 0$.  However, $\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial x} = 1$ is positive everywhere, so its integral is not zero.  (In fact, it's $\pi$.)